# XML Mapper не понимает xml файл

Tags: delphi, xml, delphi-xe

Не могу понять почему XML Mapper не работает с XML в котором есть namespaces.

У меня есть два XML Файла, специально для тестирования разбивал:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<Documents>
    <Owner>
        <FSRAR_ID>3463047</FSRAR_ID>
    </Owner>
    <Document>
        <Ticket>
            <TicketDate>2017-07-03T12:20:08.980041</TicketDate>
            <Identity>5086635403</Identity>
            <DocId>65818FBF-3174-4C52-AD85-9D3DF6CE4C56</DocId>
            <TransportId>0a37558a-ff6d-47d8-8b22-3a343dff227b</TransportId>
            <RegID>TTN-0126422299</RegID>
            <DocType>WayBill_v2</DocType>
            <OperationResult>
                <OperationName>Confirm</OperationName>
                <OperationResult>Accepted</OperationResult>
                <OperationDate>2017-07-03T12:20:08.987</OperationDate>
                <OperationComment>Накладная №VDB-00576 от 03.07.2017 00:00:00 проведена и выслана грузополучателю как участнику системы (Акт разногласий ожидается от грузополучателя).</OperationComment>
            </OperationResult>
        </Ticket>
    </Document>
</Documents>
```

Этот образец работает но это не то, что мне нужно.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<ns:Documents xmlns:tc="http://fsrar.ru/WEGAIS/Ticket" xmlns:ns="http://fsrar.ru/WEGAIS/WB_DOC_SINGLE_01">
    <ns:Owner>
        <ns:FSRAR_ID>178245</ns:FSRAR_ID>
    </ns:Owner>
    <ns:Document>
        <ns:Ticket>
            <tc:TicketDate>2017-07-03T12:20:08.980041</tc:TicketDate>
            <tc:Identity>3066635403</tc:Identity>
            <tc:DocId>21818FBF-3174-4C52-AD85-9D3DF6CE4C56</tc:DocId>
            <tc:TransportId>0a37558a-ff6d-47d8-8b22-3a343dff227b</tc:TransportId>
            <tc:RegID>TTN-7736268398</tc:RegID>
            <tc:DocType>WayBill_v2</tc:DocType>
            <tc:OperationResult>
                <tc:OperationName>Confirm</tc:OperationName>
                <tc:OperationResult>Rejected</tc:OperationResult>
                <tc:OperationDate>2017-07-03T12:20:08.987</tc:OperationDate>
                <tc:OperationComment>Накладная №VDB-00576 от 03.07.2017 00:00:00 не может быть подтверждена.</tc:OperationComment>
            </tc:OperationResult>
        </ns:Ticket>
    </ns:Document>
</ns:Documents>
```

Этот образец то, что мне нужно но он не работает в XML Mapper. Я не могу понять как его заставить работать с namespaces.

Пробовал разными вариантами сопоставление делать в XML Mapper, но он никак не видит данные при тестировании. Он Толи не понимает что префиксы это не часть имени, Толи не может определить что есть нэймспэйс. Такое чувство, что он просто видит нэймспэйсы как атрибуты. На youtube кучу роликов пересмотрел, никто с таким не работает через XML Mapper, аналогов ему тоже нет, поэтому хотелось бы понять как всё таки сделать это с ним.

Помогите разобраться пожалуйста!

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос так, чтобы он описывал конкретную проблему с достаточной детализацией для определения адекватного ответа. Не задавайте сразу несколько вопросов. См. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask для прояснения ситуации.

Comment: Попробуйте использовать крайнюю версию Delphi. Если и там не заработает, значит с неймспейсами они его работать так и не научили.

Comment: @zed Да нигде не работает. Ни в одной версии. Вроде поля создал, а данные при тесте не подгружает.